# OpenCPU installing apps

Tags: r, opencpu

I am unable to see the applications on my OpenCPU server. I git cloned https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu.demo And I had the files/folders

```
.settings
inst
man
R
.project
DESCRIPTION
NAMESPACE
README
```

I put all of these files inside `/usr/lib/opencpu/apps/opencpu.demo`

Inside the `/usr/lib/opencpu/apps/` folder i also see i have an `index.json` and an `apps-readme`

What am I doing wrong? I don't see the apps showing up on the server.

Comment: There should be a CRON job running every 15 minutes or so updating the index files. You could force it by running `sudo /usr/lib/opencpu/scripts/apps.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeroen, I had to run that manually. If the CRON job doesnt auto run I will ask another stacked overflow question. Also, I got it to work. I had to put go into the inst/opencpu/apps folder of the cloned repo and i the folders (admin,nabel,markdown,storefunction) into the apps then I ran the CRON